# How can I equally distribute the body of a formal letter in more than one page?

Tags: moderncv, letters

I have this `moderncv` formal letter template and I can not distribute the text in more than one page. The body of the letter always limits itself to one page. So if the body of the letter get too big, it makes a page break after the address of the receiver on the top and it goes to the second page and it stays there no matter how the text is getting larger. How can I equally distribute the letter in more than one page.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}        % possible options include font size ('10pt', '11pt' and '12pt'), paper size ('a4paper', 'letterpaper', 'a5paper', 'legalpaper', 'executivepaper' and 'landscape') and font family ('sans' and 'roman')

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{casual}  
                           % style options are 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{blue}                               % color options 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'
%\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}         % to set the default font; use '\sfdefault' for the default sans serif font, '\rmdefault' for the default roman one, or any tex font name
%\nopagenumbers{}                                  % uncomment to suppress automatic page numbering for CVs longer than one page


% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                       % if you are not using xelatex ou lualatex, replace by the encoding you are using
%\usepackage{CJKutf8}                              % if you need to use CJK to typeset your resume in Chinese, Japanese or Korean

% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.95, top=1cm, bottom=2cm, left=2cm, right=1cm]{geometry}
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}                % if you want to change the width of the column with the dates
%\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{10cm}           % for the 'classic' style, if you want to force the width allocated to your name and avoid line breaks. be careful though, the length is normally calculated to avoid any overlap with your personal info; use this at your own typographical risks...


\renewcommand*{\addressfont}{\small\mdseries}
% personal data
\name{John}{Templeton}
\title{Resumé title}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\address{36 Mauniour, Valybir, Alcansa}{}{United States}% optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; the "postcode city" and and "country" arguments can be omitted or provided empty
\phone[mobile]{+19193433283}                   % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\email{rrewwtrni@gmail.com}    
\extrainfo{\emailsymbol\emaillink{r\_ratreei@epi.ac.us}}

\newlength{\currentparskip}

\begin{document}
%-----       letter       ---------------------------------------------------------
% recipient data



\recipient{Department of Philology \\
Faculty of Humanities \\
University California\\
Elgsdelaan 1105 \\
1081 HV California\\
M.h.vertt@mi.us\\
Job number:5675}{}

\date{\today}


\opening{To whom it may concern,}
\closing{Yours sincerely,\vspace{-0.5cm}}
\makelettertitle
\setlength{\currentparskip}{\parskip}% save the value of paragraph spacing
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth} %create minipage
    \setlength{\parskip}{\currentparskip}% restore the value    


The body of the letter

\vspace{0.5cm}

\enclosure [\upshape Attached]{\upshape resume, writing sample.}      % use an optional argument to use a string other than "Enclosure", or redefine \enclname\


\makeletterclosing

\clearpage

  \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't put the letter in a minipage.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks. It worked. But now the text is no more justified. What can I do about that?

Comment: @barbarabeeton That question is deleted.

Comment: @user157323 I'm not familiar with moderncv so have no idea if this would work, but have you tried `\justify` at the start of each paragraph?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it seems you want the letter to be justified.

Therefore you used environment `minipage` with the disadvantage, that `minipage` is placed on one page.

Better is to use package `ragged2e`, which has a command `\justifing` to get back justified text documents, because the letter of class `moderncv` is only left justified.

With the following MWE (see important parts of code marked with `<========`)

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.95, top=1cm, bottom=2cm, left=2cm, right=1cm, showframe]{geometry} 

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{ragged2e} % to use command \justifing <=====================

%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}
%\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{10cm}

\renewcommand*{\addressfont}{\small\mdseries}
% personal data
\name{John}{Templeton}
\title{Resumé title}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\address{36 Mauniour, Valybir, Alcansa}{}{United States}% optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; the "postcode city" and and "country" arguments can be omitted or provided empty
\phone[mobile]{+19193433283}                   % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\email{rrewwtrni@gmail.com}    
\extrainfo{\emailsymbol\emaillink{r\_ratreei@epi.ac.us}}

\newlength{\currentparskip}


\begin{document}

\recipient{Department of Philology \\
Faculty of Humanities \\
University California\\
Elgsdelaan 1105 \\
1081 HV California\\
M.h.vertt@mi.us\\
Job number:5675}{}

\date{\today}

\opening{To whom it may concern,}
\closing{Yours sincerely,\vspace{-0.5cm}}

\makelettertitle

%\begin{minipage}{\textwidth} %create minipage <========================
\justifying % from package ragged2e <===================================
The body of the letter

\blindtext

\vspace{10cm}

\blindtext

\blindtext

\enclosure [\upshape Attached]{\upshape resume, writing sample.}

\makeletterclosing

\clearpage

%\end{minipage} % <=====================================================
\end{document}
```

the letter is justified and goes over two pages as wished ...

[image]